# source an audio file in repo on github pages

Tags: html, html5-audio, github-pages

I'm hosting a project on github pages and would like to play an audio file that is located in my repository through an html5 `<audio>` element. when i source it on my dev environment, the audio plays fine, but when i push to gh-pages i get a 404 console error that it cannot be found.

```
<audio ref='themeSong' src="vendor/assets/music/Tetris.mp3" autoPlay loop></audio>
```

Error:

```
GET http://myName.github.io/vendor/assets/music/Tetris.mp3 404 (Not Found)
```

i've tried sourcing it this:

```
"vendor/assets/music/Tetris.mp3"
"/vendor/assets/music/Tetris.mp3"
"http://github.com/myName/myRepo/vendor/assets/music/Tetris.mp3"
"http://github.com/myName/myRepo/tree/master/vendor/assets/music/Tetris.mp3"
```

but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try and reference the raw url

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/myName/myRepo/master/vendor/assets/music/Tetris.mp3
```

Note: a service like [rawgit.com](https://rawgit.com/faq) mentions:

> When you request a file from `raw.githubusercontent.com` or `gist.githubusercontent.com`, GitHub usually serves it (in the case of JavaScript, HTML, CSS, and some other file types) with a `Content-Type` of `text/plain`. As a result, most modern browsers won't actually interpret it as JavaScript, HTML, or CSS.
>
> They do this because serving raw files from a git repo is relatively inefficient, so they want to discourage people from using their GitHub repos for static file hosting.
>
> RawGit acts as a caching proxy, forwarding requests to GitHub, caching the responses either for a short time (in the case of `rawgit.com` URLs) or permanently (in the case of `cdn.rawgit.com` URLs), and relaying them to your browser with the correct `Content-Type` headers.

Comment: worked perfectly. on a side note, when i went to the file in my repo there was a little link there that said 'view raw'. used that link in `src` and played on both dev and gh-pages. cheers

Comment: Is this still working? The raw files don't play now from GitHub now, the play button is greyed out. Same thing happens on rawgit.

Comment: @JuanFerrer It should, but not with rawgit: https://github.com/rgrove/rawgit/issues/149#issuecomment-300056571. And check your adblocker, just in case: https://github.com/rgrove/rawgit/issues/153#issuecomment-310252191